# capacitive touch buttons through VERY thick glass or macrolon?

Tags: arduino, button, capacitive, touch-panel

for a science-project I need to create 4-5 capacitive touch buttons through thick glass or macrolon. I think we talk about 15cm atleast, if not 20. I wonder if a big coil or big sheet of tinfoil would work through the glass? The ESP32 comes with capacitive pins, can I use these or do I need to build some amp-stage to boost it? Each touchbutton should be somewhat big, like 15x15cm. Unfortunately radar and sonar can't be used for this.

Comment: Now you're mixing up things: if you use a coil, it's almost certainly not capacitive sensing anymore.

Comment: Also; even if I've posted an answer, voting to close as unclear, because your science experiment seems to be very important to what kind of answer you'll need, and therefore, should be described in the question. Happy to take back that vote if you add such information!

Comment: Optical as Marcus suggests. Photosensors on the inside, directional LEDs operated by touch switches outside. Modulate the LED with different signals (frequencies or digital codes) and you can get away with one photosensor.

Comment: Did you mean 15mm thick?  Do you have 15cm glass to test with?

Comment: Another big problem is where you're going to get glass 150 mm (6 inches) thick.  Even if you do source some, that's going to be *really heavy*.  This smells strongly of a X-Y problem.  Pop up two levels and explain what you are trying to accomplish overall.

Comment: why is the glass up to 20cm thick?

Comment: @jsotola you probably don't want to know

Answer (score 1):

15cm means that whatever capacitance your potential finger-dielectric-conductor plane plate capacitor has will be extremely small, and so will be the difference between there being a finger or not.

Since all systems on this earth expose noise, I'd be hesitant to say this might theoretically work, and I'm certain to say that no, it won't work with an Arduino.

Trying to help by adding an amplifier betrays a bit of misunderstanding what capacitive sensing is.

All in all: no, won't work. People tend to go optical in that case (it's often easy to  see a finger pressed against a flat transparent surface with even minimally cognitive vision). Or, really, use radar technologies, as you've suggested yourself.